# SSH Key doesn't work with any GIT repo

Tags: permissions, ssh, git, ssh-agent

Just installed **Ubuntu 20.04.02LTS**. I installed GIT, generated a new .ssh with this example from [DigitalOcean](http://%20%20Just%20installed%20Ubuntu%2020.04.02LTS.%20I%20installed%20GIT,%20generated%20a%20new%20.ssh%20with%20this%20example%20from%20DigitalOcean,%20after%20which%20I%20added%20the%20new%20key%20(public)%20to%20my%20github,%20bitbucket%20and%20private%20git%20repo,%20and%20it%20fails%20with%20all%20three%20with%20the%20usual%20message:%20Permission%20denied%20(publickey).%20%20I%20checked%20that%20the%20key%20was%20added%20to%20the%20agent,%20and%20that%20the%20agent%20was%20running.%20%20git%20version%202.25.1%20%20To%20test,%20i%20took%20my%20laptop%20running%2016.04lts,%20generated%20a%20new%20key,%20added%20it%20to%20github%20(waited%205min)%20and%20cloned%20a%20repo%20without%20issues.%20%20Edit:%20run%20ssh%20-i%20%7E/.ssh/private_key%20git@github.com%20and%20it%20was%20a%20pass.), after which I added the new key (public) to my github, bitbucket and private git repo, and it fails with all three with the usual message: Permission denied (publickey).

I checked that the key was added to the agent, and that the agent was running.

git version 2.25.1

To test, i took my laptop running 16.04lts, generated a new key, added it to github (waited 5min) and cloned a repo without issues.

I also run `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com` and it was a pass.

Comment: I recently had similar issues turned out that my MacOS version of the ssh-agent was automatically loading ssh keys and it was using a different accounts key and I didn't have permission to access the ones I needed.

'this is easily checked'

Try 'ssh -T git@github.com' or 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -T gitHub.com'

That will tell you which account it is identifying you as..

After that you can add -vv to the command and see which keys its offering..

If its the wrong account check with ssh-add -l and .ssh/config that its not overridden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Answer:` the file permission for the `id_rsa.pub` (public key) was 600, should be **644**